# How to delete of view button coded in viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a button in added in the viewController of Swift App, and when I change by modal segue to the next Viewcontroller this element is show in the next viewController. How can I deleted of view this?

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: {
        (session: TWTRSession!, error: NSError!) in
        ...

        print(session.userName)
        ...

    })

    logInButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(logInButton)//Here add the button
}
```

I'trying

```
 self.view.delete(logInButton)
```

But this get error.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the button from the superview? In that case you will want to try:

```
loginButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: this work, and remove in the viewController that is contained. But in te next controller this appear again then segue modal.. I don't know why, How can delete this of all views?

Comment: When you segue from one UIViewController to another, if you segue to the same custom subclass of a UIViewController that you have made, you will have all the same buttons and UI elements as the first view controller in a new instance. If I have understood correctly, you will want to make the segue go to a different view controller.